# UBUNTU 20.04 - Wired internet connection issue - UNCLAIMED NETWORK!

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I can connect internet via wifi. However, I have a problem with wired connection. My ubuntu can not see any wired connection. When I tried "lshw -C network", it print out the screen below

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 20
       serial: ec:63:d7:c7:4d:9a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=192.168.1.21 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:620-61f irq:19 memory:622f28c000-622f28ffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2e:00.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:86200000-8620ffff memory:86210000-86213fff
```

I have tried to edit ".yaml file" and other stuffs suggested on internet. I am new at Linux, so I would be very pleased if you can help me.

Comment: Please add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

Comment: Here's the output:                                                                                                           0000:2e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8162] (rev 05)
 DeviceName: GLAN
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:208f]
10000:e0:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0b0] (rev 20)

Comment: @Pilot6 OP answered your request for info.

Comment: @heynnema I have no solution for this device

Comment: You have a very unusual ethernet interface. What make/model is your computer? You may have to resort to using a USB->Ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues connecting to my Asus ROG g15 via Ethernet as well.
The Realtek driver in the kernel does not recognize this vendor ID.

This patch enables it but might take a while to be backported to other stable releases:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/72f898ca0ab85fde6facf78b14d9f67a4a7b32d1#diff-9d61beebd4949ecbf8877624e7f25547715934c98cf968bed6e3a6d47d797a7f

See if you can update the kernel to 5.15+

Alternatively you can force load the driver (as root):

```
modprobe r8169
echo 10ec 8162 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169/new_id
```